# Return URL for Joomla - creating a custom LinkedIn module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

Currently i 'm building a module that gets latest discussions in a specific LinkedIn group. I'm doing this using the 'Simple LinkedIn' class from http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/

Besides that i use the standard OATH.php.

I first created a application in PHP, making sure it worked, and it does. Next i converted it to a joomla plugin, but there is where the problem starts. The OATH session creation and authentication works fine, but then api url switches back to the defined return_url. I'm having big issues with that one.

It returns it to the Joomla homepage (mydomain/index.php) with the session tokens in the url. But when i do that I return to the homepage and not from the specific page the request was mode from. I have been looking trough a twitter module that also uses oath and than one does return all the data to the specific page and module.

Been trying for days now.

Comment: Deosn't Joomla have its own built in linked in class including an OAuth class?  It sounds like you have failed to pass the environment of the request into the plugin correctly. This should be managed automatically if you are doing the plugin correctly.  It is pretty important that you study how plugins work, they are not like modules.  Also you need to show some code, such as what event you are listening for.

Comment: Hi, i'm currently building a module, not a plugin. What i did was using the code as given above, and put it in a module for joomla.I could not find documentation in the buildin linkedin class of oath class of joomla. Can you help me in the right direction?

Comment: "Next i converted it to a joomla plugin,"  can you please update your question with correct information.  You need to post the code, it's impossible to know what you are doing.